# IE8: cannot delete 'eq(...).data(...); error

Tags: jquery, binding, internet-explorer-8

We have a huge system with event functions being bound and unbound all over the place, some by third-party libraries. I have a selector where I need to remove all existing bindings before adding the correct one. (I know, this is not good practice, but it's the only way in this case.) The code is working perfectly everywhere except IE8, where I get the error "cannot delete 'eq(...).data(...);"

Here's the code; is there any way to make this work in IE8?

```
   $('#reg-phone').keyup( function() { 
        if( typeof $('#reg-phone').eq(0).data('events') != 'undefined' ) {
            delete $('#reg-phone').eq(0).data('events');
        }
        $(this).data('placeholder', '');
        var tmp = $(this).val().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3');
       $(this).val(tmp);
    });
```

Comment: If you're just trying to remove events, why not just use `$("#reg-phone").unbind()` or `$("#reg-phone").off()`? removing "events" from `.data()` will only remove jQuery events anyway (and won't work in current versions of jQuery). also, `.eq(0)` makes no sense in this case, there can be only one `$("#reg-phone")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the code is doing with `delete` is not a good idea. To remove data you should use [`removeData`](http://api.jquery.com/removeData/) instead:

```
$('#reg-phone').eq(0).removeData('events');
```

But there is also some other strange stuff here:

- What's the `.eq(0)` for? You are using an id selector, so you are going to get at most one element back.
- Why don't you just use `.off` to remove event handlers and muck with data directly?

Comment: I don't want to use `.off` because you need to pass in the names of the events to remove. As I said, events are being bound in many places, and when I look at the jquery events on this element (using Chrome's jQuery Debugger plugin), there are over a dozen at any given time. I'd rather be able to remove all of them in one call than take a chance on missing one. That said, the `.eq(0)` was just laziness; I copied and pasted from another selector that was based on class, not id.

Comment: jQuery 1.8+ is going to barf all over that.

Comment: You don't need to pass in any events if you want to remove them all with .off according to the jQuery docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('#reg-phone').keyup( function() { 
        $('#reg-phone').off();
        $(this).data('placeholder', '');
        var tmp = $(this).val().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3');
       $(this).val(tmp);
    });
```